# rJava can load in RStudio but not in R, OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, rjava

I have rJava installed, it loads well in RStudio, but cannot load when I start R from Terminal, or from crontab. 
I've tried all possible ways I found online, what else can I do now?

0.1. Error message

> library(rJava)
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/mnt/home/dx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>     libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

1. OS version:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

2. JAVA version:

java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

3. LD_LIBRARY_PATH from RStudio:

   > Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
   >   [1] "/usr/lib/R/lib:/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server"
4. LD_LIBRARY_PATH from Terminal:

   $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

   dx@sd508:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
5. JAVA_HOME from RStudio:

> Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
>   [1] "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"

6. JAVA_HOME from Terminal:

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Take aways: 1. match LD_LIBRARY_PATH from Terminal and RStudio (I didn't match); 2. match JAVA_HOME; 3. append bin directory to PATH environmenttt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Java executable on system path? You have set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but have you appended the `bin` directory (underneath it) to the `PATH` environment variable?

eg. like this: `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

`libjvm.so` is part of Java installation, so it should be independent of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.