# How do you install dplyr-snowflakedb and rJava on Amazon Linux?

Tags: java, r, amazon-web-services, dplyr, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The goal here is to install the [dplyr-snowflakedb](https://github.com/snowflakedb/dplyr-snowflakedb) `R` package on an AWS Linux machine. The problem is that the `rJava` package will not install, it fails with the following error message:

```
“installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status”
```

The `dplyr.snowflakedb` package makes the following recommendations:

> The rJava package needs to be installed and working with Java 8 to support the SnowflakeDB JDBC requirements. This may require:
>
> - installing Java 8
> - running R CMD javareconf so R uses the Java 8 for its JAVA_HOME
> - installing rJava from source so it can be linked against Java 8

Despite trying these strategies, rJava is still not able to be installed on AWS linux.

---

The AWS linux instance is running Java 8:

```
conda activate ~/anaconda3/envs/R
(R) [ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ java -version

>>> openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
>>> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)
>>> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)
```

---

The `R CMD javareconf` command was executed:

```
Java interpreter : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_152-release
Java home path   : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv
Java compiler    : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/include -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/include/linux  -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2  -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib  -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -I/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/r-base_1570124924484/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -shared -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib/R/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv
Java library path: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/jre/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/R/lib/R
Done.
```

---

It is not clear how to install `rJava` from source or Link it against Java 8.

---

This related question: [Can't install rJava on ubuntu system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462890/cant-install-rjava-on-ubuntu-system) advises to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

however AWS Linux doesn't use `apt-get`, it uses `yum`, and the equivalent command with yum finds no package:

```
sudo yum install r-cran-rjava
>>> No package r-cran-rjava available.
```

Perhaps the issue is that JAVA_HOME is set to the `JupyterSystemEnv` rather than the `R` env?

Comment: Also considering this question as a possible resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617617/rjava-can-load-in-rstudio-but-not-in-r-os-is-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Harsh. I will take a look at that.

Comment: @Harsh how much custom code will be needed to get the ODBC connection working with dplyr the same way as the  dplyr-snowflakedb  package does? Ideally I would like to use code already written with dplyr-snowflakedb!

Comment: only indirectly related to your question. But in case you did not already know. For R(Studio) on aws+linux, there is a great image: https://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/. I am pretty sure it should be pre-configured there.

Comment: I wonder for getting R package rJava, why don't you just invoke R and then do `install.packages('rJava')` there.?

Comment: In my experience if you are not able to install rJava from R then having JRE also will help.

Comment: Try the dev version (use `install.packages("rJava",,"http://rforge.net")`
) and consider downgrading R to v3.4 per this question/answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1498373/installing-rjava-on-ubuntu-18-04-3

Comment: Countering jared_mamrot, downgrading to R v3.4 seems redundant. Simply ensuring that a proper jre, jdk, the jdbc driver and dependencies for these and R, should be sufficient to make the package work, similar to how one would do for ubuntu.

Comment: "similar to how one would do for ubuntu."  -- yes, but that doesn't work on AWS linux, or at least I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Which AWS Linux ami do you use?

Comment: Whatever the standad AMI for Sagemaker is. Is there an easy way to get the version from the command line?

Comment: cat /etc/os-release

Comment: Have you tried a solution from my answer?

Comment: NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you install not only JRE, but JDK:

   `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`
   `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`
2. Configure:
   `sudo R CMD javareconf`
3. Install rJava in R:
   `install.packages("rJava")`
4. Once you have rJava installed and verified it is using Java 8, you can install dplyr and dependancies.
   `install.packages(c("RJDBC", "DBI", "dplyr"))`
5. Installing dplyr.snowflakedb
   `install.packages("devtools")`
   `devtools::install_github("snowflakedb/dplyr-snowflakedb")`

If you have issues with install devtools try to instal dependencies or try another repo:

- `install.packages("devtools", dependencies=TRUE)`
- `install.packages('devtools',dependencies=TRUE,
     repos='https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/')`